# Pass a string from C# Application to an unmanaged C++ DLL using Pipes

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I am trying to pass a string from my C# application into a C++ DLL using Pipes. How can I make my C++ DLL take in the textBox1.Text string?

The DLL is unmanaged.

I would like the DLL to possibly send out the textBox1.Text in a MessageBox every time the button on the C# application is pressed.

C# Code

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int num = 0;
            using (NamedPipeClientStream stream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "execute", PipeDirection.Out))
            {
                redo:
                try
                {
                    stream.Connect(350);
                }
                catch (TimeoutException)
                {
                    if (this.open)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        try
                        {
                            stream.Connect(500);
                        }
                        catch (TimeoutException)
                        {
                            num++;
                            if (num < 3)
                            {
                                goto redo;
                            }
                            MessageBox.Show("Something happened.");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox1.Text))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                        {
                            writer.Write(textBox1.Text);
                            writer.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("welp");
                    }
                }
                stream.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

C++ Code

```
#define BUFSIZE 1024

    void main() {

            LPTSTR lpszPipename = "\\\\.\\pipe\\execute";
            HANDLE hPipe;
            BOOL flg;
            DWORD dwWrite, dwRead;
            char szServerUpdate[200];
            char szClientUpdate[200];

            hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
                lpszPipename,             // pipe name 
                PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,       // read/write access 
                PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe 
                PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode 
                PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode 
                PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances  
                BUFSIZE,                  // output buffer size 
                BUFSIZE,                  // input buffer size 
                0,                        // client time-out 
                NULL);                    // default security attribute 



            ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL);

            //Read from client
            flg = ReadFile(hPipe, szClientUpdate, strlen(szClientUpdate), &dwRead, NULL);

            if (flg) //Read something from the client!!!!
            {

                CString csMsg, csTmp;

                for (int i = 0; i<dwRead; i++) {
                    csTmp.Format("%c", szClientUpdate[i]);
                    csMsg += csTmp;
                }

                string strX(csMsg.operator LPCSTR());

                MessageBox(0, strX, "MessageBox caption", MB_OK);
            }
```

Comment: Any direction or something. Kinda leaving me empty handed.

Comment: I added an attempt.

Comment: Thanks for adding your c++ code

Comment: Passing strlen(szClientUpdate) to ReadFile() is quite wrong, that's putting the chicken before the egg.  You don't have a string yet.  You need to specify the buffer size, so use sizeof(szClientUpdate) instead.

Comment: I have defined Buffsize now. Sorry, I left that out of the code.